# Getting CSS3 PIE.htc to show up in child elements when used on parent element

Tags: internet-explorer, css, html-components

So I'm using PIE.htc from http://css3pie.com/ and using it on a parent element `div#page-contents`, as well as some elements inside that (`dl.mainfeatures`, `div#login-stuff`, etc.). On IE 8 (haven't tested other versions yet), the CSS3 code I use appears just fine on the parent element, but none of the child elements are showing anything (rounded corners, box shadow, nothing). Even regular CSS attributes (background-color, border) aren't showing up.

Is there some issue with applying an HTC fix to child elements and their parent element at the same time? How can I get this to work?

Comment: There shouldn't be a problem with what you've described, but could you provide some code or a link to an example so we can actually see what you're doing, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any actual example code it's hard to see what the problem actually is.

However you may want to double-check against the list of known issues with CSS3Pie; there are a few. The vast majority of weird glitches with CSS3Pie turn out to be related to `position` and `z-index`, so these are the first things to check.

Also, if you really can't solve it, ask on the CSS3Pie forum -- the author is very good at responding to questions. (plus there are a bunch of other posts already there from people asking similar questions, so you may find someone else has already asked the same thing)